# Paging in MVC + Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I need to add paging for my users view page, i got all the datas using Json to show in the table..i need to add paging and and also i can able to change number of users to show in a particular page. any simple Jquery plugin or source code will be very much helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a grid that takes json data and automatically does paging for you, you might be interested in jqGrid ( http://www.trirand.com/blog/ ) which is a great way to hook up a dataset to a powerful front end grid. I'm not sure if a grid is necessarily the right choice for your use case, but it seems to be what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `flexigrid` plug-in:

http://www.flexigrid.info/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Telerik's MVC Components](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx). Is it simple and easy to use and build on the top of jquery and it is Open source.